# Oracle Application Server SSL Certificates preventing connection to Apache service

Tags: oracle, apache, ssl

We've got an Apache instance deployed through Oracle Application Server. It's currently installed with the default wallet, and, the self-signed certificate. We've got a GEOTRUST certificiate, imported the Trusted Roots and imported the new Cert to the Wallet Manager. We've then updated the SSL properties of the VHOST and the HTTP_SERVER through Enterprise Manager.

Things have restarted fine, however, we now can't connect to the Apache service, we're getting the error:

> call to NZ function nzos_Handshake failed

This seems to point to a problem with the root certs, but in my opinion, these are registered with the Wallet correctly.

Anyone seen this before and have some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with an Apache/JBoss configuration
look at your httpd.conf, you should have three lines:

SSLCertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/public.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /usr/local/ssl/private/private.key
SSLCACertificateFile /usr/local/ssl/crt/EV_intermediate.crt

The last line is needed because the Geotrust root CA is not known by most older and some newer servers (you would not have to do this with a verisign or instantssl cert, for instance).